# Erro Json Flutter

Tags: json, image, flutter, dart, provider

I have this error programming in flutter and dart when executing the files from a .json
Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown resolving an image codec:
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      Uri.parse (dart:core/uri.dart:792:17)
#2      _Uri.resolve (dart:core/uri.dart:2592:27)
#3      NetworkImage._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:93
#4      NetworkImage.load
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:54
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("null", scale: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkImage widget needs a real image URL as a parameter. So you have to provide it like this:

```
  NetworkImage(
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547721064-da6cfb341d50",
  ),
```

Read more from [here](https://educity.app/flutter/how-to-display-images-from-internet-in-flutter).